# why writing unit test methods?

Tags: testing

I find many people wasting a lot of time to write hundreds of lines to test applications. Sometimes changing the application architecture just to make the test methods easier to write.   Why don't we test methods by using. I mean we act just like users and we try to give different inputs and see if the result is what we are expecting ?

Comment: There is a massive amount on information on test driven design and testing in general on the net. Your question is not specific enough for SO

Comment: it's specific just read it again, everybody tests in some way(test Methods), I am suggesting another way (using), tell me who's the best and why ?

Comment: The simple answer is cost. It costs almost nothing to run 1000's of automatic tests, users cost many many many times more.

Comment: not users,but you as a programmer you act like user and you test, i think clicks coast less then writing hundreds of lines !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and answer this with more details. I think the argument is why write a ton of unit tests instead of just clicking around the application to see if it works as expected. The logic is that it takes less time to click a few buttons than it does to write thousands of lines of code to test.

I've worked in several companies with public facing websites and I can tell you that the "click around" testing approach is terrible. Reasons:

1. It doesn't scale. If you have a non-trivial application, you will spend hours with every release testing by acting as a user.
2. It's a waste. You end up running through the same tests over and over from your own bias. You'll always test the features you know best and you end up in a routine. "I click on this, then that, then this ... and the application is good!" It's just a waste of time if you always test the same things.
3. You don't get coverage. Similar to (2) ... you think you hit every part of the application, but you won't.
4. It's hard to re-create state. You might have a bug that only appears after a user clicks on page A, then B, then A again, then D, then C, then A. After all that clicking the system is in an interesting state. You'd never re-produce that with casual clicking.
5. Even if you find a bug, you've only hit the tip of the iceberg. Have fun trying to figure out which method beneath that UI feature is actually the problem.

I could go on and on, but unit tests hit all these problems. There are even tools to show you how much code coverage you have with your tests.